# How to order by case in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, case

Please view the below SQL query and its results.

```
WITH Temp ([Description], [Amount], [OverdueBy])
AS 
(select Description, SUM(Amount) as Amount, (DATEDIFF(day,DueDate,GETDATE())) as OverdueBy  from brvAPAllInvoices 
Where PaidDate is null and APCo = 1
Group By Description, DueDate

)


SELECT CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN 'Overdue by 46+ days+' 
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy < 45 THEN 'Overdue by 31-45 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy < 30 THEN 'Overdue by 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy < 14 THEN 'Overdue by 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy < 7 THEN 'Overdue by 1-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy > -7 THEN 'Due in 0-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy > -14 THEN 'Due in 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy > -30 THEN 'Due in 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy > -45 THEN 'Due in 45+ days'
ELSE 'Less than that' END AS OverdueRange,
Count(*) as OverdueCount,
Sum(Temp.Amount) as [Total Amount]
From Temp

group by CASE WHEN OverdueBy >= 46 THEN 'Overdue by 46+ days+' 
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 31 and OverdueBy < 45 THEN 'Overdue by 31-45 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 15 and OverdueBy < 30 THEN 'Overdue by 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 8 and OverdueBy < 14 THEN 'Overdue by 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy >= 1 and OverdueBy < 7 THEN 'Overdue by 1-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= 0 and OverdueBy > -7 THEN 'Due in 0-7 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -8 and OverdueBy > -14 THEN 'Due in 8-14 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -15 and OverdueBy > -30 THEN 'Due in 15-30 days'
            WHEN OverdueBy <= -31 and OverdueBy > -45 THEN 'Due in 45+ days'

ELSE 'Less than that' END
```

Results:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+
|     OverdueRange      | OverdueCount | Total Amount |
+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+
| Due in 0-7 days       |           14 | 101631.81    |
| Due in 15-30 days     |          337 | 491171.32    |
| Due in 8-14 days      |            7 | 1829.62      |
| Less than that        |           26 | 23325.68     |
| Overdue by 1-7 days   |          112 | 389606.12    |
| Overdue by 15-30 days |           18 | 49001.10     |
| Overdue by 31-45 days |           13 | -92473.18    |
| Overdue by 46+ days+  |           50 | 380746.95    |
| Overdue by 8-14 days  |           11 | 18399.05     |
+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I want to manually specify the order or the OverDueRange field so that it is not alphabetical however, in the order that I want.

To achieve this, I have added the following code to the bottom of my query:

```
ORDER BY (CASE OverdueRange
    WHEN 'Overdue by 46+ days+'      THEN 1
    WHEN 'Overdue by 15-30 days'     THEN 2
    WHEN 'Overdue by 8-14 days'      THEN 3
    WHEN 'Overdue by 1-7 days'       THEN 4
    WHEN 'Due in 0-7 days'           THEN 5
    WHEN 'Due in 8-14 days'          THEN 6
    WHEN 'Due in 15-30 days'         THEN 7
    WHEN 'Due in 45+ days'           THEN 8
    ELSE 100 END) ASC, OverdueRange DESC;
```

When I execute the code, I receive the following errors:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'OverdueRange'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'OverdueRange'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'OverdueRange'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'OverdueRange'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'OverdueRange'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'OverdueRange'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'OverdueRange'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'OverdueRange'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to repeat the entire case statement in your `ORDER BY`. If you want to refer to the case statement by name, then use a derived table. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23881150/3574819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `case` statement as all.  Just do:

```
ORDER BY MAX(temp.OverdueBy) DESC;
```

This will choose the maximum value from each range.  By the definition of the range, it should be in the order that you want (you could also use `MIN(temp.OverdueBy))`.

Comment: This still gives an error message:
"Invalid column name 'OverDueBy'."

Comment: @pgunston . . . Unless your system is case sensitive, that doesn't make sense.  The same variable is used in the `select` and `group by`.

Comment: Exactly why I made this post.

Comment: I just fixed it by using 
ORDER BY MAX(Temp.[OverdueBy]) DESC;

Thanks for your help.